# Can't update symfony recipes

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I just upgraded to Symfony 5.3 and I try to update recipes.

composer return many recipes to update with:

```
composer recipes:install vendor/package --force -v
```

When I enter this line, I get an error I can't solve:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  Cannot run "sync-recipes --force": git not found.
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please share more details. Is "git not found" something you have debugged? Is git really installed and usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem's solved!

In ubuntu Software & update, all of the ubuntu software list were disabled, then I could not use the "apt-get install git" command.

I checked cd-rom, mains and universes list softwares and it works fine.

I installed git then update recipes became possible.

Thanks you everybody! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove your flex in your vendor?

```
rm -rf vendor/symfony/flex
```

And clone the symfony flex again via git

```
git clone git@github.com:symfony/flex.git vendor/symfony/flex
```

Then run the command

```
composer sync-recipes --force
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems than git is not install on my computer. When i go to Git website to install it, it say to add it using command : "sudo apt-get install git" or "sudo apt-get install git-all". However, nothing is working, terminal say that git package is not available..

Comment: Normally this should work when installing git with the command 

`apt-get install git`

But otherwise you have another solution : 

Go to the following URL address [link](https://github.com/symfony/flex) and you can download the repository as a zip file